# Как называется способ вёрстки, когда сервер определяет устройство клиента (смартфон или десктоп) и в зависимости от этого выдаёт web-страницу?

Tags: html, вёрстка, bootstrap, mobile-development, mobile-web

Вопрос в заглавии. Пример: сайт vk.com. Если зайти на него с ПК, то откроется десктоп-версия, и если тут же перейти в инструменты разработчика (F12) и отобразить страницу как на смартфоне (Ctr+Shift+M), то станет видно, что страница всего лишь уменьшилась в масшатабе, и элементы на ней никак не подстроились под изменения размеров экрана (в отличие от сайтов которые свёрстаны, скажем, на bootstrap'е, такие как twitter.com, например).

Как этот способ называется, чтобы подробнее о нём загуглить? Есть ли для него какие-то библиотеки?

Comment: "Адаптиваная", библиотеки - есть, много. И все-таки, в случае bootstrap не сервер определяет устройство. Там все на CSS-медиа-запросах.

Comment: @mrEvgenX спасибо